# Get linux kernel's dump_stack to char array instead of to console

Tags: linux-kernel, stack-trace, dump, printk

So, when I call dump_stack(), it printk's to dmesg. But, I need it to, let's say, 'print' it to char array, so that I could display the stack much, much later, in a different place.

Is it possible? It would help me sooo much with debugging a nasty bug I'm having!

Comment: You could implement a custom dump_stack() in the kernel (e.g., dump_stack_to_buffer(...)) that would send the same stack info to a char buffer.

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: @IanTraum Go to the place in the kernel source where dump_stack() is implemented, copy it replacing the function name, then replace printk() with a buffer copy or sprintf().  If this were to be a permanent change that you would want to upstream you might design it more elegantly.  This should work for debugging.

Comment: See replies to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863122/how-to-include-c-backtrace-in-a-kernel-module-code/, especially Eugene's reply.

Answer (score 0):

The tool that you need is called `save_stack_trace`.

First read [Baruch's Linux kernel deferred stack trace blog](http://baruch.siach.name/blog/posts/linux_kernel_deferred_stack_trace/). Then read [Eugene's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863122/how-to-include-c-backtrace-in-a-kernel-module-code/5869657#5869657) to a similar SO post.